# Time complexity of 2 nested loops

Tags: time-complexity

I want to detect the time complexity for this block of code that consists of 2 nested loops:

```
function(x) {
    for (var i = 4; i <= x; i++) {
        for (var k = 0; k <= ((x * x) / 2); k++) {
            // data processing
        }
    }
}
```

I guess the time complexity here is O(n^3), could you please correct me if I am wrong with a brief explanation?

Answer (score 2):

the time complexity here is O(n^2). Loops like this where you increment the value of i and k by one have the complexity of O(n) and since there are two nested it is O(n^2). This complexity doesn't depend on X. If X is a smaller number the program will execute faster but still the complexity stays the same.